# Conversion of $2\:\text{m}^2$ in $\text{cm}^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, unit-of-measure

I had an evaluation and had to go from $2\:\text{m}^2$ to $\text{cm}^2$ and I made a rule of three simple: $1\:\text{m}^2 = 10000\:\text{cm}^2,$  $2\:\text{m}^2 = 20000\:\text{cm}^2.$ But the teacher told me wrong, he told me it was like this: $1\:\text{m}^2 = 100\times 100.$  $2\:\text{m}^2 = 200\times 200 = 40000\:\text{cm}^2.$ I think it's wrong and if so, tell me why, in order to explain it to me and that it's correct. Thank you.

Comment: Yes but please give me and answer to say him because i tell that he was wrong but he said no because 2m²=200cmx200cm

Comment: maybe he was referring to $(2 m)^2$ that is a square with a side $2 m$ long. Clarify further with him.

Comment: You converted two square-meters into square centimeters. You teacher solved a totally different problem: to express the area of a square with side length of 2 m in units of cm²

Comment: A meter has 100 cm, so multiplication of area is by the square of that , i.e., by $10^4$.. giving $20,000 \,cm^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course we have

- $1\,m^2 =100\times 100 \,cm^2 = 10'000 \,cm^2 \implies 2\,m^2 =20'000 \,cm^2$

and

- $2\,m\times 2\,m = 4 \, m^2= 40'000 \,cm^2$

Answer (score 1):

There is possibly some ambiguity over *two metres squared*

- An area of $2$ square metres is the same as an area of $20000$ square centimetres, for the reason you give
- A square with a side of $2$ metres has an area of $2^2=4$ square metres; in the same way a square with side $200$ centimetres has an area of $200^2=40000$ square centimetres

Comment: and the ambiguity is worse in Spanish - guessing from your name -   with *dos metros cuadrados*: does that suggest  *dos-metros cuadrados* or *dos metros-cuadrados*?

Comment: is not the same and is really obvious in spanish because our grammar is different. "dos-metros cuadrados" doesn't have any meaning, because any operation after the measure is over the measure. If not, you would said: dos (al cuadrado) metros. I think the problem is english grammar here :D

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is wrong since $100*100*2\neq 200*200$. This is because on the RHS there are two factors of $2$ whereas there is only $1$ factor of a $2$ on the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$1\:\text{m}=100\:\text{cm}$$ so $$1\:\text{m}^2=100\cdot 100\:\text{cm}^2=10000\:\text{cm}^2$$ so $$2\:\text{m}^2=2\cdot 10000\:\text{cm}^2=20000\:\text{cm}^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine a square with side measurements of $1m$. Its area is $1m*1m=1m^2$

Now, $100cm=1m$. If we imagine a square with side lengths $100cm$, it's area is $100cm*100cm=10000cm$.

Imagine a square with sides $2m$. It's area is $4m^2$.

With sides of $200cm$, we get an area of $200cm^2=40000cm^2$

And so on and so forth. Basically, you're completely correct, $1m^2=10000cm^2$.